# Mount denied dev environment on Docker macOS

Tags: macos, docker-compose

When trying to docker compose in my dev environment I get the following error:

Error response from daemon: Mounts denied:
The path /com.docker.devenvironments.code/.postgresql/data is not shared from the host and is not known to Docker.
You can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> Resources -> File Sharing.

The according line in my compose file:
volumes:
- ../.postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

I couldn't find anything on this, I hope someone can help me out! Thanks ahead!

I tried to add /com.docker.devenvironments.code to the file sharing but obviously it couldn't recognise it because its in a volume :x

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.